# Google app engine, query multiple entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have following 2 entities.

```
class Photo(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    registerdate=db.DateTimeProperty()
    iso=db.StringProperty()
    exposure=db.StringProperty()

class PhotoRatings(db.Model):
    ratings=db.IntegerProperty()
```

I need to do the following.
Get all the photos (Photo) with iso=800 sorted by ratings (PhotoRatings).
I cannot add add ratings inside Photo because ratings change all the time and I would have to write entire Photo entity every single time. This will cost me more time and money and the application will take performance hit.
I read this,
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling
But could not get much information from it.

EDIT: I want to avoid fetching too many items and perform the match manually. I need fast and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do relational database queries with an explicitly non-relational Datastore.

As you might imagine, this presents problems. If you want to the Datastore to sort the results for you, it has to be able to index on what you're wanting to sort. Indices cannot span multiple entity types, so you can't have an index for `Photo`s that is ordered by `PhotoRatings`.

Sorry.

---

Consider, however - which will happen more often? Querying for this ordering of photos, or someone rating a photo? Chances are, you'll have far more views than actions, so storing the rating as part of the `Photo` entity might not be as big a hit as you fear.

Comment: Thanks! So this is a limitation, no way around it. I guess I will have to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [billing docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing) you'll notice that an Entity write is charged per **changed** number of properties.

So what you are trying to do will not reduce write cost, but will definitely increase read cost as you'll be reading double the number of entities.

Comment: Oh right, I was under the impression that each write will be charged for the entire entity regardless of number of changes. It seems like way too much effort to optimize this without good results. Thanks for pointing this out. No i will just test how much of performance hit it will take as my entity is already quite large.